# login loop on admin account, guest works fine

Tags: gui, login-screen, administrator

As you can tell I am having some issues. I am a gamer, and not having write privileges would be a death sentence to any gamer. With this guest account when I log. I have tried 2-3-4 fixes, Even did another `fsck`, another issue, not this one. My point is. there is something wrong with either admin, GUI, or something in between. Cause I can log in terminal or shell whatever it is called. But not with GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

likely the problem lies with the "hidden" files and directories in your home directory.  These all start with a "." and basically hold configuration information, which may be outdated after an update.  The guest account starts fresh, so doesn't have that problem.  Search this site for "login loop" and there are many solutions -- basically just put all the "dot" files into a temporary directory, so they don't intefere with login and see if that works.  They should be recreated as needed, like the guest account does, but if you really need something you put aside, it is always in the temporary directory to bring out.