# Ubuntu 18.04, login loop after installing cuda

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, login

After installing cuda and new nvidia drivers on Ubuntu 18.04, I am now stuck on the infamous login loop. Before asking for help, I carefully browsed the internet but I am now running out of ideas! I will tell you what I tried and the output.

-Checking permission of Xauthority/ICE authority : this file does not even exist
-Checking permissions of /tmp : everything is fine.
-Startx works and i get a rustic, but functional GUI. Now  Xauthority exists and has the good permissions.
-CHanging-reconfigurate display manager (GM3 or lightdm) : done (no change)
-purging and reinstalling nvidia drivers : done. Nothing changed.
-Create a new user and see if I can login : Done and **I can log in!**
-After installing cuda, i added a line in the .bashrc file to add the cuda repository to the file. Since then i commented this line on the bashrc file but nothing changed.

-Resetting the gnome/unity configuration of the main user account : done. It did not change anything. I did it with

```
dconf reset -f /org/gnomes/
```

and with :

```
rm -rf .gnome .gnome2 .gconf .gconfd .metacity
```

I am now running out of ideas. I could reinstall everything on this new account but I would actually prefer to get my original login account back. If you have any suggestion, i would love to hear them.

PS : I am rather a newbie when it comes to command lines and linux. I can run any command line, try to post some logs, but if you can be as precise as you can, I would be very grateful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not Xauthority/ICE authority. It's .Xauthority/.ICE authority.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/916991/login-loop-on-admin-account-guest-works-fine/916999#916999 for an answer that deals with all the other dot files, which are causing the problem.

Comment: @heynnema . Thank you for your  answer. i checked the hidden files so the ones with dot. they still have the good permissions.

Comment: @ubfan.  Thank you for your answer. i will move the hidden files and if it works, will isolate the main culprit. will keep you updated!

Comment: @ubfan1 moving .hidden_files_folders can be tricky, as some get recreated automatically, and then you may loose your settings. `.local` and `.config` are two such examples.

Comment: @Henridecagny check file ownership, not just permissions, on those two files are important. They should NOT be root:root. Also, see my note to ubfan1 about playing with hidden files. Recheck your edits to .bashrc, as mis-edits there could cause your problem too.

Comment: So i moved some .files and it resolved the problem. I moved most of them back, and it still works perfectly. I will keep the other user account just in case something goes south again but I think the problem is solved. Thank you very much everybody!

I am rather new to this platfor, is there any way to say that the problem is solved?