# recover from shim fail after change from grub2 to shim in 18.04 can not login

Tags: boot, grub2, login, moklistrt

Apparently, ubuntu 18.04 has decided to make system changes without asking.

One of these was a change from Grub2 64 bit which was fine, to shim which has now locked up my computer and made it unusable. Login does not work. Boot gives error message "failed to set moklistrt"

Since I can not login, how can I use live boot cd to repair this?

Comment: Forgot to include running on AMD 8300 8 cores, 240 GB SSD, 16 GB ram, /home on 3 TB hd.

Comment: I didn't get this change on my 18.04 UEFI system.  There was a `grub-efi-amd64*` update on 6/4, but it did not cause any problems.

Comment: Thanks, not sure what is wrong here but even a full grub-install did not fix it. When booting, I do not get a boot menu screen, it just goes straight to the error, then boots ubuntu and the login screen comes up but I can not login, it just reloads the login screen again..

Comment: Did a complete reinstall, the same problem. I did leave out an important bit of information. The /home directory is reassigned to a partition on another drive in fstab  18.04 new install boots with /home on the new drive but the problem appears again when /home in fstab is pointed to the old /home partition.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the full output of `sudo blkid` and the full contents of `/etc/fstab/`.

Comment: Sounds like a problem in your "hidden" files (those beginning with a dot). See https://askubuntu.com/questions/916991/login-loop-on-admin-account-guest-works-fine/916999#916999

Comment: Thanks Organic Marble: As soon as I can get it uploaded. Do not have network access from shell nor will flash drives work.

Comment: Was not able to provide requested info due to that computer not having internet connection.

Comment: Resolved problem by complete new install, including overwriting /home and all files. The cause in this case was in copying files from another computer, the ownership, group, etc. were corrected but it still would not boot. Apparently, something in the xconfig was not right although the Xauthority etc, was fixed.